# Problem with .htaccess doesnt see rewrite rules

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I setup a virtual host and put in htaccess some rewrite rules... But they dont work.. Only the rules in virtual host config work..
What am i doing wrong?

**.htaccess**

```
setEnv TZ Europe/Athens
Options +FollowSymLinks

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

php_value max_execution_time 600
php_value max_input_time 600
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 16M
php_value memory_limit 200M
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 21600
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off


    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/home/?$ /index.php?__i18n_language=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/press/([0-9]+)?$ /press.php?__i18n_language=$1&id=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/profile/(.+)?$ /static.php?__i18n_language=$1&tag=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/links/?$ /static.php?__i18n_language=$1&tag=links [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/corporate/?$ /static.php?__i18n_language=$1&tag=corporate [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/products/?$ /static.php?__i18n_language=$1&tag=products [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/products/(.+)?$ /static.php?__i18n_language=$1&tag=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/press/?$ /press.php?__i18n_language=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/sitemap/?$ /sitemap.php?__i18n_language=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/financial/?$ /financial.php?__i18n_language=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/contact/?$ /static.php?__i18n_language=$1&tag=contact [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/newsletter/?$ /newsletter.php?__i18n_language=$1 [L]
```

**Virtual Host file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName dev.skiandboard.gr

    DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ski\content"
    <Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>






    ErrorLog "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ski\error.log"

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

RewriteEngine On



RewriteRule ^/(.+)/cat/(.+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /category.php?__i18n_language=$1&category_tag=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/cat/(.+)?$ /category.php?__i18n_language=$1&category_tag=$2&page=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/prd/?$ /product.php?__i18n_language=$1&product_tag=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/static/(.+)/?$ /static.php?__i18n_language=$1&page_tag=$2 [L]



</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved... It seems that rewrite rules in htaccess dont want  / at start...
weird..

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in your "error.log" and "access.log" files. What lines appear when you go to a page?